# Hierarchical data run infinitely in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, recursion

I am using SQL Server 2008.In my databse one table like:

```
------------------------------
id   parentId   name
------------------------------
1    NULL       india
2    1          gujrat
3    1          Maharastra
4    1          rajsthan
5    2          ahmedabad
6    2          rajkot
7    NULL       USA
8    7          newyork
1    3          mumbai
1    3          goa
1    4          jaipur
1    7          californiya
```

Here i want to get this data with it's level in hierarchy, so i create query like:

```
with RecursiveTable_CTE (Id,Parentid,Name_cte,Hlevel)
as
(
select id , parentId, name, 0 as Hlevel from treeTable where id = 1
union all
select t.id,t.parentId,t.name, Hlevel + 1 as LEVEL  from treeTable as t inner join RecursiveTable_CTE as rtc on t.id = rtc.Parentid
)
select * from RecursiveTable_CTE option (maxrecursion 0)
```

and also try

```
with RecursiveTable_CTE (Id,Parentid,Name_cte,Hlevel)
as
(
select id , parentId, name, 0 as Hlevel from treeTable where parentId is null
union all
select t.id,t.parentId,t.name, Hlevel + 1 as LEVEL  from treeTable as t inner join RecursiveTable_CTE as rtc on rtc.id = t.parentId
)
select * from RecursiveTable_CTE option (maxrecursion 0)
```

but both result infinite loop.

can any one help me?

Comment: Why do you have duplicates in 'ID' column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the query you're after is this:

```
with RecursiveTable_CTE (Id,Parentid,Name_cte,Hlevel)
as
(
select id , parentId, name, 0 as Hlevel 
  from treeTable 
  where parentId is null
union all
select t.id,t.parentId,t.name, rtc.Hlevel + 1 as Hlevel  
  from treeTable as t 
  inner join RecursiveTable_CTE as rtc on t.Parentid = rtc.id
)
select * from RecursiveTable_CTE
```

The problem is though that I think your data is not correct and `id` and `parentId` are swapped in some rows. I used this data:

```
insert into treeTable values (1,    NULL,       'india')
insert into treeTable values (2,    1,          'gujrat')
insert into treeTable values (3,    1,          'Maharastra')
insert into treeTable values (4,    1,          'rajsthan')
insert into treeTable values (5,    2,          'ahmedabad')
insert into treeTable values (6,    2,          'rajkot')
insert into treeTable values (7,    NULL,       'USA')
insert into treeTable values (8,    7 ,         'newyork')
insert into treeTable values (9,    1 ,         'mumbai')
insert into treeTable values (10,   1 ,         'goa')
insert into treeTable values (11,   1 ,         'jaipur')
insert into treeTable values (12,   7 ,         'californiya')
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a80f/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here in your case ther 1 is top level but again 1 has parents 3,4,7.
 your infinite loop is due to your wrong herarchy.

```
id   parentId   name
------------------------------
1    NULL       india
1    3          mumbai
1    4          jaipur
1    7          californiya
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicates in the ID column, Is that a typo? If you don't have duplicates

```
CREATE TABLE states 
    ( 
         [id] INT,[parentid] INT,[name] VARCHAR(11) 
    ); 

INSERT INTO states 
    ([id],[parentid],[name]) 
VALUES  (1,NULL,'india'), 
    (2,1,'gujrat'), 
    (3,1,'Maharastra'), 
    (4,1,'rajsthan'), 
    (5,2,'ahmedabad'), 
    (6,2,'rajkot'), 
    (7,NULL,'USA'), 
    (8,7,'newyork'), 
    (9,3,'mumbai'), 
    (10,3,'goa'), 
    (11,4,'jaipur'), 
    (12,7,'californiya'); 
WITH recursivetable_cte (id, parentid, name_cte, hlevel) 
 AS (SELECT id,parentid,name,0 AS Hlevel 
     FROM   states 
     WHERE  parentid IS NULL 
 UNION ALL 
     SELECT t.id,t.parentid,t.name,hlevel + 1 AS LEVEL 
     FROM   states AS t 
    INNER JOIN recursivetable_cte AS rtc 
    ON t.parentid = rtc.id) 
SELECT * 
FROM   recursivetable_cte 
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Szymom is right.id should be unique.though in this query no need of changing table data

see the change,

```
;with RecursiveTable_CTE (Id,Parentid,Name_cte,Hlevel)
as
(
select id , parentId, name, 0 as Hlevel from @t where id = 1 **and parentId is null**
union all
select t.id,t.parentId,t.name, Hlevel+ 1 as LEVEL  from @t as t 
inner join RecursiveTable_CTE as rtc on t.Parentid = rtc.id **and t.id<>1**
)
select * from RecursiveTable_CTE
```